# Print the name and the size of the largest file

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, directory

I have to create a script that takes the argument that should be the name of a directory. From there it has to print all the files and then print out the largest one and its size. Please help! Would an array with `ls -l` help?

```bash
yourfilenames=`ls $1`
for eachfile in $yourfilenames
do
   echo $eachfile
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `du` command to get the size of specific file(s).

If you want to get the output of all files and then print the largest one you can use this:

```bash
find /path/to/yourDirectory/ -type f -exec du  {} + | sort -rn | tee  >(echo -e "\nThe largest one is: $(head -1)")
```

The command `find /path/to/yourDirectory/ -type f -exec du {} +` will get the size **only of the files** (subdirectories will not be considered for printing their size, only their files)

With `sort -nr` the output will be sorted from largest files to smallest ones.

With `tee  >(echo -e "\nThe largest one is: $(head -1)")` the output will be redirected to the `stdout` and will also be redirected to the process `echo -e ...` and therefore `$(head -1)` will print only the first line of the redirected output which represent the largest file size.

When you print with this: `echo -e "\nThe largest one is: $(head -1)"` the output will be something like this:

```
The largest one is: 736K        ./path/to/yourdir/largestfilesize
```

As you can see above the size is printed before the path. If you want to get  the path before the size you could use:

```
find /path/to/yourDirectory/ -type f -exec du  {} + | sort -rn | \
tee  >(echo -e "\nThe largest one is: $(head -1 | awk -v OFS='   ' '{print $2,$1}')")
```

---

If you want to get the file sizes in **human-readable** format (4M,5G,3K, etc) then you should use the correct options to print in that format:

```bash
find /path/to/yourDirectory/ -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -rh | \
tee  >(echo -e "\nThe largest one is: $(head -1)")

#or

find /path/to/yourDirectory/ -type f -exec du -h  {} + | sort -rh \
tee  >(echo -e "\nThe largest one is: $(head -1 | awk -v OFS='   ' '{print $2,$1}')")

#du -h prints the file sizes in human readable format
#sort -h will sort the output comparing the human
#readable numbers (e.g., 4M,5G,3K, etc)
```